# Dividing a typeof number is Infinity?

Tags: javascript

Sorry in advance is this is an obvious question. I am dividing two variables and receiving Infinity as my result. Here are the details:

```
typeof a //'number'
typeof b //'number'
typeof (a-b) //'number'
typeof ((a-b)/(b)) //'number'
     a - b = xxx.xxxxx //this works
     (a - b)/b = Infinity
```

Here are some more details:

```
a and b are five decimal places (XXX.XXXXX)
// the variables are generated from ....
var z = document.getElementById('foo').getBoundingClientRect()
var y = document.getElementById('bar').getBoundingClientRect()
var a = z.x
var b = y.x
```

`foo` is a div and `bar` is a table
`a` is generated outside a function
`b` is generated inside the function from an `.on('scroll', ....)`

```
<div id="foo">
  <table id='bar'>
  </table>
</div>
```

I am assuming my issues comes from the `typof = 'number'`.
In trying to find my answer in the following:

- [typeof number + typeof number = NaN?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9148499/typeof-number-typeof-number-nan)
- [Infinity is some number in javascript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24166320/infinity-is-some-number-in-javascript)
- [Why does typeof NaN return 'number'?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2801601/why-does-typeof-nan-return-number)
- https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/isInteger
- [Overloading Arithmetic Operators in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1634341/overloading-arithmetic-operators-in-javascript) (which I did not understand)
- https://www.sharkys.com/food/menus/ (don't fault me. I was hungry. )

Comment: What is the question?

Comment: How about this... `typeof NaN === "number"`! Did I just blow your mind? Also, JavaScript doesn't have a `Division by Zero` error. Instead, you get `infinity`.

Comment: `typeof(Infinity)` equals `number` so `((a-b)/(b))` is probably evaluating to `Infinity` as well.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It happens because `b` is 0, and dividing by 0 in JS returns Infinity. In addition the type of Infinity is number.

```js
var a = 5
var b = 0

console.log('a ', typeof a);
console.log('b ', typeof b);
console.log('(a-b)/(b) ', (a-b)/(b))
console.log('(a - b)/b ', (a - b)/b)
console.log('typeof Infinity ', typeof Infinity)
```

Answer (score 1):

Probably, you divide by zero. Right?

[image]